# When will k parameter be changed?

Tags: stake-pool, staking, decentralization, proof-of-stake

Is there any news on when k=1000 will happen?

Comment: How do you know that it will happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2020/11/05/parameters-and-decentralization-the-way-ahead/

"As a result, our aim is to move to k=1,000 during March 2021. We recognize the importance of economic factors that also strongly influence pool profitability and will continue to consult widely with the community on the plan; the social dynamics of the network should also not be underestimated."

Comment: this really isn't a question for stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

### Epoch 234

On December 06th 2020, IOHK increased the *k parameter* from 150 to 500. This affected the *optimal* number of pools in the Cardano network. This change lowered the saturation point for stake pools from 220M ada to 64M, resulting in the loss of some rewards in oversaturated pools.

### Epochs 300...320 ?

At the moment there are [*>3000 stake pools*](https://adapools.org). The Cardano network reached full decentralization and, apparently, very soon, the k parameter will be set to 1000, which will lead to a decrease in the saturation point from 64M to 32M per pool.

### k=1000

I think that you don't need to redelegate your stake at the last moment (when k will be changed). You are free to pick a new stake pool below 32M and you will not miss any rewards.